# When should I use :c:expr to write inline code in Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

[According to the documentation of Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/domains/c.html#inline-expressions-and-types), inline code can be written with :c:expr:. Here is an example:

```c
This is a simple typecast: :c:expr:`(int*)var`.
```

Using features of reStructuredText, we can also write

```c
This is a simple typecast: ``(int*)var``.
```

The outputs look different. With the former, the inline text has no gray background, cross-references are made automatically (when possible), the output is syntax-highlighted, ... .

I was wondering when I should use one of them and not the other. Since they appear different, the rendered document looks somewhat strange if both are used.